# computer freezes after about 7,000 iterations of an .exe in a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

i searched for command line applications to report on mp3 tags and found three: mpgtx, id3 and id3tool. Unfortunately all three of them freeze my computer after reporting about 7,000 items. I have 120K items. I've tried straight .exe, start and call as part of my experimentation. I've tried calling a separate batch file in place of the executable line. No luck.

Here's a simplified code that fails:

```
 for /l %%g in (1, 1, 100000) do (
 id3.exe "filename.mp3" >nul
 )
```

mpgtx runs out of CPU. id3 and id3tool show plentiful CPU and memory (in Process Explorer) before they freeze the computer.
any thoughts on how to use these tools, or on alternate tools without this problem for win/xp?
thx

Comment: I feel the need to point out that the code you have posted will run `id3.exe` only on `filename.mp3`, but it will do so 100000 times. I feel like that isn't what you're trying to do.

Comment: hence my labeling it "simplified code"

Comment: It's not simplified, it's wrong. The example you provide should be able to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

ExifTool worked ... but only because it has it's own recursive switch and doesn't get called 100,000 times.

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Review: "Insanely great tool with a long learning curve ..."